# Reading specific part from txt file is not working

Tags: android, text

This is my code:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Bonbon info");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File f = new File(dir, "paket.txt");

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();


        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line;

            br.skip(60);

            int charactersRead = 0;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && charactersRead < 12) {
                            text.append(line);
                            text.append('\n');
                            charactersRead++;
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }

        final String URL = text.toString();

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setText(text);
```

Reading is working, but i can't read only 12 characters, it reads trough the end of file,  don't know why.

Comment: I don't understand. You're incrementing the CHARACTER count by one for every LINE that you read?

Comment: Don't know, i was given example here ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your file is relatively short.

You're calling `BufferedReader.readLine()`, which in an attempt to be efficient is sucking up a big chunk of the file stream rather than going through it character-by-character.

If you want that finer control over what you read, it's probably worth using an `InputStream` implementation straight up.

Comment: I have an text file with aproximetly 90 characters, but i wan't to read characters from 61 to 72 and save it in string.... So can't you give me soma advice how to do this with this method ??

Comment: With such a small file, the easiest thing is probably to read the whole thing into a `String` and call `substring()` on that to extract the desired chunk.  However, if your data gets bigger, more complicated, or changes frequently, you'll want to rethink that strategy.